# How to ensure a recursive function isn't called again before it returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I'm making an RPG in JavaScript and HTML5 canvas. For the dialog, I added a "typing" effect to  appear as if NPC's dialog is being typed out automatically (letter by letter).

This function is fired when a user presses a button. While the function recurs through the string.length, appending each character at the given index, I don't want the user to be able to press the button again until the function stops (reaches end index of string).

To do that, I've added `$("#responseButton").prop('disabled', true);` while the function is recurring, and `$("#responseButton").prop('disabled', false);` when it's index matches dialog string.length.

**Problem:** It seems that the button is disabled as expected while the function recurs, but as soon as it's done, I can keep clicking the enabled button... the function seems to be called several more times over each time the button is pressed... even if the recurrence from the previously called one hasn't finished... this results in the text being constantly overwritten.

**Question:** How do I ensure the function is done recurring before it can be called again? It's like there's a lag time if I keep clicking the button till when it runs again...

```
typeEffect : function (index) {     
    if (index >= game.data.NPCdialog.length) {
        game.data.enableCycle = true;
        $("#responseButton").prop('disabled', false);
        return;
    }
    else{
        $("#responseButton").prop('disabled', true); //wait until typing is done before user can press again
        $("#npc_dialog").append(game.data.NPCdialog.charAt(index++));
        var t = setTimeout('Utilities.typeEffect('+ (index) +')', 40);      
    }       
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single-threaded.  Unless you deliberately relinquish control, no other Javascript function can be called.

**EDIT**

Norgard writes:

> surely you see the setTimeout, there

I didn't see the setTimeout and stop calling me Shirley.

And I think his plan would work, except that several events are queued up before the handler is fired.

Growler, I think the problem you are having is that you assume that the handler will be fired, and the button disabled, after the very first click and therefore no subsequent events could be generated.  This is not, I believe, correct.

Instead, try this:

```
typeEffect : function() {
  var enabled = true;

  var process = function(index) {
    if (index >= game.data.NPCdialog.length) {
      game.data.enableCycle = true;
      enabled = true;
      $("#responseButton").prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
      $("#npc_dialog").append(game.data.NPCdialog.charAt(index));
      setTimeout(function() {
        process(index+1);
      }, 40);
    }
  };

  return function(index) {     
    if (enabled) {
      $("#responseButton").prop('disabled', true);
      process(index);
    }
  };
}(),
```

Comment: surely you see the setTimeout, there.

Comment: ...looks like I picked the wrong week to quit sniffing glue. That said, I believe it would be `.charAt(index)` and then `process(index+1)`, because of when the postfix is resolved. `.charAt(++index)` would be `.charAt(index+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that setTimeout returns immediately and then your code continues.

You need a function that calls itself after a timeout and checks to see if the button should be enabled.

Here's a demo:
http://cdpn.io/Idypu

Comment: For some reason this still doesn't solve my issue. I'm able to keep clicking on the button after it becomes enabled again and there is a delay where it runs the call over and over again

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, the part that's biting you is the combination of event-reaction, asynchronicity and a recursive function which might not kick in how and when you'd expect.
It goes a little further, but that's enough to illustrate where things go wrong, without getting into the meta-programming between the cracks of JS and the browser-engine powering it.

Now that the other answers have shown you why it doesn't work the way you think, I'd suggest that the root of the problem is that you're trying to manage something which should happen exactly once (toggling the button) inside of something that could happen a hundred times, where if you wrote a little bit more code and turned it inside out, it would be a lot easier to visualize.

Perhaps a refactor that looks a little something like this, might make things simpler:

```
var button = {
    el : $("#responseButton"), // cache your references
    setDisabled : function (state) { button.el.prop("disabled", state); },
    enable  : function () { button.setDisabled(false); },
    disable : function () { button.setDisabled(true ); },
    handleClick : function () {
        button.disable();
        Utilities.typeEffect(0, function () { button.enable(); });
    }
},

dialogBox = {
    // if you're going to call this 100x in a row, cache it
    el     : $("#npc_dialog"),
    append : function (text) { dialogBox.el.append(text); }
},

sec = 1000,
textSpeed = {
    fast   : 1/25 * sec, // 25x /sec
    medium : 1/10 * sec, // 10x /sec
    slow   : 1/ 5 * sec  //  5x /sec
};

button.el.on("click", button.handleClick);



Utilities.typeEffect = function (index, done) {
    if (index >= game.data.NPCdialog.length) {
        game.data.enableCycle = true;
        return done();
    } else {
        var character = game.data.NPCdialog[index];
        dialogBox.append(character);
        setTimeout(function () {
            Utilities.typeEffect(index+1, done);
        }, textSpeed.fast);
    }
};
```

You should notice that I changed very, very little inside of the actual `.typeEffect`.
What I *did* do was build a quick little `button` abstraction that holds a cached reference to the element (don't make jQuery look for it, on your page, 25x per second), adds some quick'n'dirty helper methods...  ...and then I gave the button control of its event-handling, including knowing how to clean up, when the time comes.

If you'll notice, I gave `.typeEffect` one more parameter, `done`, and the argument I passed it is a function that is defined by `button`, which knows how to clean itself up, when everything is finished. The function isn't any bigger, and yet, I'm now performing the input-blocking/unblocking exactly once, by passing a callback.

Better yet, I can guarantee that it's blocked right before the start of the recursion, and it's unblocked right after the last recursion occurs, without any ill-defined state to get in the way.

I also cached the dialogue box, to again speed the process along;
jQuery does wonders, these days, but this should still be cached.

If I were to take it further, I'd probably make `typeEffect` a plugin for a dialog-writing component, so that several different types of effects could be dropped in.
I'd probably also start passing the recursing function the other arguments it cares about (text-speed, a reference to the dialogue box, et cetera), so that they're easier to swap, and the function becomes more reusable (and easier to see that it works).

Note that this isn't really *the* answer. It's ***a*** solution, which should not only solve the problem, but illustrate how to prevent it, in the future.
If it works, use it, if it doesn't, don't.
If the concept works, but it's not your style, then change it (though, avoid using a string in `setTimeout`... that should have stopped being taught years and years ago; performance-killer, safety-hazard if you're mashing in user-created strings, easy to make non-strict eval-context mistakes...  ...all of the good stuff).

Comment: Norguard, how else can I simulate a typing effect without a setTimeout delay?

Comment: @Growler you require a `setTimeout`, or alternatively, a `setImmediate` or `requestAnimationFrame`, in order to get the effect you want in JavaScript (other solutions would completely lock-up the browser window). The thing that you should be avoiding is the string inside: `setTimeout("doStuff(data);", 50);`. Instead, pass it a function: `setTimeout(function () { doStuff(data); }, 50);`. It's faster, safer and more predictable.